# You must specify a network_id in your 'goerli' configuration in order to use this network

Tags: smartcontracts, bitcoin-testnet, ethereumtesterprovider

why it is showing this error , i have given network id : 5

what should i do to remove this error ? i am failing in deploying the contract please let me resolve my problem as soon as possible

#goerli testnet , truffle framework